# Why is my map() with function arrows not working?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, mapping

This problem was resolved using standard if/else block in one of my previous posts regarding using map(). But now I have another problem. Here's the solution with the if/else:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Transforming Data</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Transforming Data</h1>
  <p>Open the console</p>

  <script type="text/babel">

    // Editing one object in an array of objects

    let schools = [
      {name: 'Yorktown'},
      {name: 'Stratford'},
      {name: 'Washington & Lee'},
      {name: 'Wakefield'}
    ];

    const editName = (oldName, newName, arr) =>
      arr.map(item => {
        if (item.name === oldName) {
          return {
            ...item,
            name: newName
          }
        }
        else {
          return item
        }
      });

    let updatedSchools = editName('Stratford', 'HB Woodlawn', schools);

    console.log(updatedSchools[1]);  // {name: "HB Woodlawn"}
    console.log(schools[1]);  // {name: "Stratford"}

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

But, doesn't want to work for me when using function arrows. The substitution is not taking place when mapping. But, I'm using the same solution--namely: 'name: name'. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Transforming Data</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Transforming Data</h1>
  <p>Open the console</p>

  <script type="text/babel">

    let schools = [
      'Yorktown',
      'Stratford',
      'Washington & Lee',
      'Wakefield'
    ];

    const editName = (oldName, name, arr) =>
      arr.map(item => (item.name === oldName) ?
        ({...item, name: name}) :
        item
      );

    let updatedSchools = editName('Stratford', 'HB Woodlawn', schools);

    console.log(updatedSchools[1]);  // Stratford
    console.log(schools[1]);  // Stratford

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your new array is a string array, not an object array, and therefore doesn't have a `name` property, meaning `item.name` will always return undefined

Comment: `item.name` is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, my original post about this problem contained an erroneous array of strings when it should have been an array of objects. My apologies for wasting everyone's time. The following code does indeed work fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Transforming Data</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Transforming Data</h1>
  <p>Open the console</p>

  <script type="text/babel">

    let schools = [
      {name: 'Yorktown'},
      {name: 'Stratford'},
      {name: 'Washington & Lee'},
      {name: 'Wakefield'}
    ];

    const editName = (oldName, name, arr) =>
      arr.map(item => (item.name === oldName) ?
        ({...item, name: name}) :
        item
      );

    let updatedSchools = editName('Stratford', 'HB Woodlawn', schools);

    console.log(updatedSchools[1]);  // {name: "HB Woodlawn"}
    console.log(schools[1]);  // {name: "Stratford"}

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your new array is a string array, not an object array, and therefore doesn't have a name property, meaning item.name will always return undefined.

If you'd like to continue using a string array, you will have to modify your function like so:

```js
    let schools = [
      'Yorktown',
      'Stratford',
      'Washington & Lee',
      'Wakefield'
    ];

    const editName = (oldName, name, arr) =>
      arr.map(item => (item === oldName) ? name : item);

    let updatedSchools = editName('Stratford', 'HB Woodlawn', schools);

    console.log(updatedSchools[1]);  // Stratford
    console.log(schools[1]);  // Stratford
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original array was just a string array not an array of objects and it does not have object with `name` property hence when you are accessing each array elements using `.map()` you are not able to access the `name` property with your current code. If you want to achieve the same result with your string array then you can try with the below code which just iterates over each array string element and replace the required element. In your original code `item.name` returns undefined.

```
let schools = [
      'Yorktown',
      'Stratford',
      'Washington & Lee',
      'Wakefield'
    ];

    const editName = (oldName, name, arr) =>
      arr.map(item => (item === oldName) ?
        name : item
      );

    let updatedSchools = editName('Stratford', 'HB Woodlawn', schools);

    console.log(updatedSchools[1]);  // HB Woodlawn
    console.log(schools[1]);  // Stratford
```

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain what was wrong with the original code and how you fixed it.